# Python invalid syntax

Tags: python

Учусь писать алгоритмы на Python.
И возникла ошибка invalid syntax
код прилагаеться ниже
ругаться на строчки 9, 2, 18

```
def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(list)-1

while low <= high:
    mid = (low + high)
    guess = list[mid]
    if guess == item:
        return mid
    if guess > item:
        high = mid - 1
    else:
        low = mid + 1
    return None

my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

print binary_search(my_list, 3)
print binary_search(my_list, -1)
```

Comment: А после invalid syntax что написано? Обычно такие пояснения критически важны и помогают все самому исправить. Лучше не перечислять номера строк, вторую строчку найти легко, а 9-ю или 18-ю отсчитывать сложно и отбивает желание вам помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ругается скорее всего на неизвестные переменные low и item.
Проблему можно решить, если сдвинуть строки начиная с while и до return (не включая return) вправо до уровня предыдущей строки high = ...
Примерно так:

```
def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(list)-1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)
        guess = list[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            low = mid + 1
    return None

my_list = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

print binary_search(my_list, 3)
print binary_search(my_list, -1)
```

Python чувствителен к отступам, на строке с while он думает, что функция binary_search уже кончилась и поэтому не может понять, что это за переменные - в основной программе ведь их нет, они есть только в функции.

И если у вас Python 3, то нужно ставить скобки у print:

```
print(binary_search(my_list, 3))
print(binary_search(my_list, -1))
```

Comment: ```print binary_search(my_list, 3)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: @Саня У вас Python 3, дополнил ответ

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо вопрос решен все заработало.

Comment: @Саня Тогда отметьте мой ответ специальной галочкой как правильный :)